# Prove that it is possible to make a self-financing portfolio

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, portfolio-optimization, martingale

I would like to prove that if there exists $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ satisfying $\mathbb E[\int |X(s)|^2 d[Y]_s]<\infty$ (for a standard filtered probability space $(\Omega, F,( F_t)_{t\ge 0},\mathbb P)$ and $Y$ - an $\mathbb R^{n+1}$-valued cadlag semimartingale, with finite quadratic variation $[Y]_t$, where $ F_t^Y:=\sigma(Y_s,\,s\le t)$ denotes the natural filtration of $Y$), then we can always choose $X_0$, s.t. $(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$ is self-financing. Everything is in continuous time.

As I realised, I should find the exact form of $X_0$, which satisfies our conditions.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. That's a lot of fancy looking and sounding maths you wrote down, but what is the real financial problem that you are trying to solve? To start with, specify $X_0$ and $X_i$. E.g. given a simple market consisting of money market account $X_0$ and a **tradable** asset $X_1$ I can give you a self-financing strategy without any maths: borrow $X_1$ amount, and buy one unit of $X_1$ and do nothing else.

Comment: Well, in general, this is a part of my big solution for option pricing with non-gaussian fluctuations. And as a part of it, I'd like to prove that for any market, which is a Markov process and also normalised, if I have a "portfolio" $(X_1, ..., X_n)$ which partially satisfies the self-financing portfolio definition, I always can find $X_0$, which can make my portfolio truly self-financing. So, exactly, it's a mathematical problem, and I need a general case, which I then can adapt to different situations.

Comment: If the at least the $X_0$ is something you can trade and sell short, then what you might be looking for is Lemma 10.3 from Bjork's "Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time" book, 2nd edition. That lemma does not assume Markov processes, only that the portfolio strategy  is adapted and admissible (eg no doubling strategy)

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful!

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to ask/post any follow up questions you may have.